# Checking if some dates fit between a start and an end date range and total count of matched dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a `Start Date` and `End Date` column in one of the SQL Server tables. I have a list of bank holiday dates. I need to test each start and end date range per row to check how many of the holidays falls within that range and total count of those.

I am currently achieving this by doing `CASE WHEN` statements / holiday date as following

```
select 
    a.StartDate, 
    a.EndDate,
    (CASE when '2017-01-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-04-14' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-04-17' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-05-22' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-07-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-08-07' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-09-04' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-10-09' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-11-11' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-12-25' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2017-12-26' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-01-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-03-30' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-04-02' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-05-21' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-07-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-08-06' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-09-03' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-10-08' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-11-11' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-12-25' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2018-12-26' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-01-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-04-19' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-04-22' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-05-20' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-07-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-08-05' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-09-02' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-10-14' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-11-11' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-12-25' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2019-12-26' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-01-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-04-10' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-04-13' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-05-18' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-07-01' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-08-03' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0  end)+
    (CASE when '2020-09-07' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-10-12' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-11-11' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-12-25' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)+
    (CASE when '2020-12-26' between a.StartDate and a.EndDate then 1 else 0 end)
from
    (select '2017-01-01' as StartDate, '2019-12-31' as EndDate) a
```

Is there a better way of doing it? Can SQL test for each START and END Date range how many holiday dates intersect in a single line?

Comment: If your dates are in a table (or you use `VALUES` to make a derived table), you could just do a join or a subquery to count the number of dates that are between your start and end dates. e.g. A simple approach would be: `select startdate, enddate, (select count(*) from (values ...) as bankholiday(holidaydate) where bankholiday.holidaydate >= a.startdate and bankholiday.holidaydate <= a.enddate) from (select '2017-01-01' as StartDate, '2019-12-31' as EndDate) as a;`

Comment: Though if you're only testing against a single start and end date, the query becomes even simpler by just doing `select startdate = '2017-01-01', enddate = '2019-12-31', count(*) from (values ...) as bankholiday(holidaydate) where holidaydate >= '2017-01-01' and holidaydate <= '2019-12-31';` and you could of course use variables to change the start and end dates if needed.

Comment: You should have a `calendar` table. it makes things much easier

Comment: @ZLK thanks for the response. I tried the following as you suggested and it returned an error. select StartDate, EndDate, (select count(*) from (VALUES '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26') as bankholiday where bankholiday >= a.startdate and bankholiday<= a.enddate) from
(select '2017-01-01' as StartDate, '2019-12-31' as EndDate) as a

Comment: `VALUES` would be a list of bankholiday dates and would need to be formatted like such: `FROM (VALUES ('2017-01-01'), ('2017-04-14'), ('2017-04-17'), ...) AS BankHolidays(HolidayDate)` or something like that.

Comment: @ZLK I honestly don't know how to thank you. It worked !!!!  I am learning so much everyday from this forum and experts like you. Keep up the good work mate !!!  select StartDate, EndDate, (select count(*) from (VALUES ('2017-01-01'), ('2017-04-14'), ('2017-04-17')) AS BankHolidays(HolidayDate) where BankHolidays.HolidayDate >= a.startdate and BankHolidays.HolidayDate<= a.enddate)
from
(select '2017-01-01' as StartDate, '2019-12-31' as EndDate
union all
select '2017-01-01' as StartDate, '2020-12-31' as EndDate)a

Comment: That's good, though honestly, you should look into having a calendar table as Squirrel suggested (a calendar table being a list of all dates, with optional information about whether it's a holiday, whether it's a weekend, etc - you can find examples of this by searching for "calendar table sql server" or something like that) or at least a table that manages holidays if not all dates. That way you don't have to use values, you can just look up the dates in a table and compare them to your own dates.